# PostgreSQL change data type default query

Tags: postgresql

While I am doing monitoring with my PostgreSql server, I found out that this query frequently shown up.

```
select t.oid, t.typname from pg_type t where t.typtype='b'
```

and because I have a lot of table, that query will take long time to process.
Is it possible for me to custom that query into another query like

```
select t.oid, t.typname 
from pg_type t 
  left join pg_type base_type on t.typelem=base_type.oid 
where t.typtype='b' 
  and (base_type.oid is null or base_type.typtype='b')
```

or maybe another suggestion will be good

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out what issues this query, then you can fix the problem. It may well be some ORM, framework or other tool.

Having extremely many tables, users, schemas or other objects is a bad idea, because the catalogs are not built and indexed for that.